# How to add a mailto button to TinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, mailto

I need to add a mailto button to TinyMCE in WordPress.  Has anybody already done this?  Or any tops on how to go about it?

Comment: What would a `mailto` button do exactly?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean a button that will convert text into a `mailto:` link?

Comment: i assume you want to send the whole editor content to someones mail adress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given you are wanting to put this into WordPress I assume you want to simply insert a href="mailto:" type tag into your document for the currently selected text.

The simplest way is to create a basic plugin. You can do this in the same page that tinyMCE is initialised into. The example below will wrap the currently selected text with a static mailto.

```
 tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.MailToPlugin', {

  init : function(ed, url) {
   ed.addCommand('mceMailTo', function() {
    var linkText = ed.selection.getContent({format : 'text'});
    var newText = "<a href='mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=testing'>" + linkText + "</a>"
    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, newText);
   });

   // Register example button
   ed.addButton('mailto', {
    title : 'MailTo',
    cmd : 'mceMailTo',
    image : url + '/images/mailto.gif'
   });
  }
 });

 // Register plugin with a short name
 tinymce.PluginManager.add('mailto', tinymce.plugins.MailToPlugin);
```

You will of course need to create an image (mailto.gif) for the toolbar button.

You then simply add the following to your plugin list

```
plugins: '-mailto'
```

and put *mailto* on the toolbar.

Of course, if you want to allow the end user to specify the email address and subject, then you will need a dialog. There is a good example of how to create a plugin on the TinyMCE site in [Creating a Plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin)

Unfortunately I can't comment on how you would do either of these in WordPress but I suspect you will need to customise your version of WordPress tinyMCE plugin.

Comment: That's great!  Works a treat.

Comment: Not work a version different =[ .. i see 2010, is now 2017 all different ... try compare http://fiddle.tinymce.com a version

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class I built in WordPress [my tutorial](http://unrelatedmedia.ca/tutorial/wordpress-adding-custom-buttons-to-tinymce/) and then make the calls to your javascript files through instantiating the class.  At least, regarding the reference to adding it to your plugins.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have tinyMce Advanced plugin installed. Then, you can just use the insert / edit link button from the tinyMce editor. You don't need a different button. In the destination URL add this

```
mailto:my-mail@my-domain.com
```